# How do I get my logo and tagline to line up with my navigation?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have been working on a drop down navigation which I have got close to how I like but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the Logo (which is really just h1 text) and the tagline, to line up with my navigation.

The html for the logo and tagline is:

```
<div class="logo grid_5 omega">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="default.html"><h1>karma.</h1></a></li>
      <li><p id="tagline">A stop motion animation</p></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

And it's corresponding CSS is this so far:

```
/* Header (Logo) -------------------------------------------------- */

.header.grid_12.omega {
    margin-top:40px;
    box-shadow:0 3px 10px #222;
    background:#FFFFFF;
}

.logo.grid_5.omega {
    float:left;
}
```

The navigation's html is:

```
<nav class="grid_7 omega">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="design.html">Process</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Models</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Backgrounds</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Animation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Post-production</a></li>                
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="style.html">Style</a></li>
              <li><a href="reflection.html">Reflection</a></li>            
           </ul>
        </div>

  </nav>
```

And it's CSS is:

/* Drop down nav ---------------------------------------- */

```
nav ul ul {
    display:none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }

nav ul {
    background: #FFF; 
    padding: 0 20px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #4b545f;
    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
        color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
    }

nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
        position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 40px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #4b545f;
            }
```

However, as you can see: it's a little off:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3x72.jpg

Comment: have you tried to set similar line-height to both h1 and nav ?

Comment: can you please add a screenshot, what are you looking for

Comment: @SonasishRoy if you click on the imgur link you can see my header screenshot. Basically I want the logo and the tagline (which is currently underneath the logo to display next to the logo and both of them to be perfectly aligned with the navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Give an id to your main ul and give some top margin?

## HTML

```
<nav class="grid_7 omega">
    <ul id="navi">
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

## CSS

```
ul#navi{
    margin:30px 0 0 0; /*adjust your top margin*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this

**html**

```
<div class="logo grid_5 omega">
    <ul>
      <li><h1><a href="default.html">karma.</a></h1></li>
      <li><p id="tagline">A stop motion animation</p></li>
    </ul>
 </div>

<nav class="grid_7 omega navigation">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="design.html">Process</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Models</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Backgrounds</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Animation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Post-production</a></li>                
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="style.html">Style</a></li>
              <li><a href="reflection.html">Reflection</a></li>            
           </ul>
        </div>

  </nav>
```

**css**

```
.header.grid_12.omega {
    margin-top:40px;
    box-shadow:0 3px 10px #222;
    background:#FFFFFF;
}

.logo.grid_5.omega {
    float:left;
}
.logo.grid_5.omega li{
    float: left;
    line-height: 40px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 25px;
    padding-top: 14px;
}

.navigation{
    float:left;
}
nav ul ul {
    display:none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }

nav ul {
    background: #FFF; 
    padding: 0 20px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #4b545f;
    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
        color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
    }
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/pYkvK/1/)

Comment: Yes, thanks, that made the tagline come up in line with the navigation but the logo still sits much lower. I know I could just use position:relative and bring it up but it seems a bit hacky. What is the best way to get it up? Here's what it looks like now.http://imgur.com/BoPYuDa

Comment: if you post your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ that will relay helpful for me to edit the code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rybkq/there is my code. I've already hacked my way through it but it's still strange. I think it might be that chrome is defining default css for the h1 tag.

Comment: also your logo li structure should be

<li><h1><a href="default.html">karma.</a></h1></li>